# Getting error when I give install aws, awscli in my EC2 linux instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Please check the below error:

[image: Error O/p]

My EC2 instance is below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-246:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-9-246 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install awscli`. It's o/p is as below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-246:~$ sudo apt-get install awscli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
awscli is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 198 not upgraded.
```

But when I give `aws --version`, I'm getting errors:

[image: Error O/p]

Please check and advise.

Comment: Have you run the install with "sudo"?

Comment: Of course... since it is for development questions, i asked here a development question. Because I got errors while I'm deploying a DEVELOPMENT environment in ec2 linux instance. Thanks anyway for the comment.

Comment: Yes Raman. I ran it with sudo

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

shows that the locale is unknown.

So to fix this issue, you have to export UTF-8 in your bash profile.

You can do this by adding the two lines below to ~/.bash_profile

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Hopefully it works for you.

Cheers!

Max

Comment: Max..
I added both the lines to my bash profile. (~/.profile in my case)

Comment: But it did not fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you run `$ source ~/.bash_profile` after you added the 2 lines? Or restart your terminal.

Comment: Restarted my terminal. It worked. Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: @MaxGoh Just pointing out `export` is missing in above answer. It didn't worked for me as provided in above code. Then I have added export into it and it worked. Thanks. `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`